# User input filename

Tags: c++, stdstring, c-strings

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

const int WL = 20;
const int WR = 1000;

void READ (ifstream &, char[], char[][WL], int &);
void PRINT (char [][WL],  int, int,  int );

int main()
{
    ifstream file;
    string fileName;
    cout << "enter file name";
    getline(cin, fileName);
    char name[] = fileName;
    char Word[WR][WL];
    int row = 0;
    int WordMax;
    int WordMin;

    file.open(name);
    assert(! file.fail() );
    READ (file, name, Word, row);
    file.close();
    cout << "file successfully opened" << endl;

    cout << "word length: \n";
    cout << "min: ";
    cin >> WordMin;
    cout << "max: ";
    cin >> WordMax;

    PRINT(Word, row, WordMin, WordMax);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

As I understand, the problem is that I can't use `fileName` in `char name[]`, because it is `string`, but `char name[]` will be used in the code later... what can I change to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Don't introduce the new variable `name` for this, just use the [`c_str()` method of `std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str):

```
string fileName;
//...
getline(cin, fileName);
//...
file.open(fileName.c_str());
//...
READ (file, fileName.c_str(), Word, row);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just convert the string to a char once, like this `filename.c_str()`

For example, `char name[] = fileName.c_str();`

Comment: So just replace string fileName with fileName.c_str()? Because then it says it is undeclared, how can i declare this?

Comment: @Mastarg I believe you have to `#include <string>` or `#include <string.h>`

Comment: The method `std::string::c_str()` should not require any additional headers than `string`. What do you mean "it says it is undeclared"?

Comment: `fileName' undeclared (first use this function)

Comment: Well, maybe there is way to change " char name[] = "filename"; " So that user would input that filename?

Comment: -1! this is simply a wrong advice and will crash. You don't understand what you are doing.

Answer (score -2):

First, define : `char name[sizeof(fileName)]`;
Then, you can use `strcpy(name, fileName.c_str());`
Should work but you may need to manage the null case by checking the fileName value before passing it to the char array.

Comment: `sizeof(fileName)` is NOT in any way related to the length of the string. Additionally you can not determine the length of the user's string at compile time.

Comment: char name[sizeof(fileName) ];
    cout << "enter file name";
    getline(cin, fileName);
    strcpy(name, fileName.c_str()); like this? Becasue same problem

Comment: @Vortico: fileName.size() instead?

Comment: @TimChristin You're still not able to determine the size of the user's input at compile time. There is no way to handle all possible user inputs with a static char array, so you must use a char pointer (e.g. dynamic array) like in Rews Prog's answer.

Comment: Wow that's sounds so bad! Didn't realized this limitation... thanks for the precision Vortico! Hope the post is resolved now.

Comment: -1: `sizeof (fileName)` is **wrong**, it typically returns `4` (for most `std::string` implementations)